# Assign string to array of class type in c#

Tags: c#

I have one class where in I am defining 2 variables.

```
public class attachment_type
{
   string filename;
   int cnt;
}
```

In the 2nd class, I want to assign string value to filename. In already existing code they have made array of class type.

```
public class mainApp
{
   attachment_type[] at = new attachment_type[dt.rows.count];
   at[0].filename = "test File" 
}
```

I am not able to do the above. Error comes at line `at[0].filename = "test File";`

> Object reference not set to an instance of object.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign a new instance of your class for every entry in the array:

```
public class mainApp
{
    attachment_type[] at = new attachment_type[dt.rows.count];
    at[0] = new attachment_type();
    at[0].filename = "test File" 
}
```

With `attachment_type[] at = new attachment_type[dt.rows.count];` you only allocate a new array of a given size, however the array does not have any content so far. You only say that you need some memory, but not for what.